# Hyper-v Network degraded with latest LIS

Tags: hyper-v

I installed a CentOS 6.3 X64 VM on windows server 2012 Hyper-v. Everything works fine. But there's a message in the VM network status: "Degraded(Integration service upgrade required)" which worries me. I had installed the latest Linux Kernel and Integration Service(Version 3.4), why the network is degraded? When I create the VM, I used the legacy network adaptor, after install the LIS, I removed the legacy network adaptor, and replace it with normal network adaptor.

Kernel

- 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64

LIS

- kmod-microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.x86_64.rpm
- microsoft-hyper-v-rhel63.3.4-1.20120727.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host knows the currently available version of the integration services. When you start the vm, integration services in the vm ask the host for the current version. If the guest is on an earlier version, you get that message.

Without looking up the current version, I would simply assume that the most recent integration services haven't made it in to your repo yet. They will eventually and you can upgrade then.

Until then, there is probably no harm in using the older version. It is definitely better than running the legacy adapters and no integration services.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I also had a problem with large VHDX using the latest LIS. The Microsoft developer said they knew the issue and they will release the patch, but they don't know when.